# Visual C++ doesn't show both redefinition error

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

VC++ now give me C2371 redefiniton error but it doesn't show me two definitions. 
It just show me one! I want to see other definition too.

Is there a way to see both definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Visual Studio doesn't show secondary info lines in the Error List view, which is available from the actual compiler output. Try double clicking the error in the "Error List" view, then switch to "Output" view and the corresponding output line should be highlighted. Here, in the output, you should see a second line saying "something.something.h(123) : see declaration of 'foo'". Double click that line and you'll end up at the first declaration.

Comment: Thank you, normally I use Xcode in OS X and I forgot these trick in VC, now I know :)